# Does Java `synchronized` block lock on Object reference, or value?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, synchronized-block

Given the output shown below:

```
    Path path1 = Paths.get("/Users/someone/foo");
    Path path2 = Paths.get("/Users/someone/foo");
    System.out.println(path1.toString() == path2.toString()); // outputs false
    System.out.println(path1.toString().equals(path2.toString())); // outputs true
```

Given the following two threads, is it possible for both threads to be running in the critical section at the same time?

```
    // Thread 1
    synchronized (path1.toString()) {
        // Critical section
    }

    // Thread 2
    synchronized (path2.toString()) {
        // Critical section
    }
```

Comment: Each object has its own monitor; that is what is acquired by the synchronized block. As such, there will only be mutual exclusion if `path1.toString() == path2.toString()`.

Comment: In general, synchronizing on the result of method call is not a good idea: even if you're synchronizing just on `path1.toString()` in both threads, you might get no mutual exclusion at all, if it's always returning a new object (you don't know if this is the case, and it could change arbitrarily).

Comment: And you certainly cannot count on those references to be the same. Most likely they won't be. Anyway, why would you lock on a `String`? `String` carries around a whole lot of freight and semantics to use merely as a lock object. You only need an `Object`.

Answer (score 7):

The reference *is* the value. This is a distinction without a difference. `toString()` is a reference. It won't be the same as any other `toString()` value unless both have been interned, or they both originated from identical or the same string literals.

Comment: I think OP was wondering if two strings that test as equal (using `equals()`) would be enough to ensure thread safety.

Comment: @TedHopp I don't see any point in speculating about what he may or may not have meant. I'm answering the question he asked.

Comment: Yes Ted, I was wondering if `equals()` or `==` is used when judging two objects are equal in the `synchronized ()` keyword.

Comment: @albusshin Then you should have said so in your question. As soon as you actually write it down you can see that it doesn't make sense. Why would `synchronized` be comparing objects?

Comment: @EJP I see your point. Pardon my jargon, but I don't know what is the name of the thing we are comparing when we call `.equals()`?

Comment: @albusshin There is no 'thing'. It's a method. It compares anything it likes, or nothing, and returns a value.

Answer (score 4):

As is documented in the [Java Language Specification, section 14.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) (JLS), the `synchronized` statement locks on objects. If you're thinking of "value" as the string value (as in `path1.toString().equals(path2.toString())`), then then answer is "no"—your code is almost certainly not thread-safe. In the parlance of the JLS, if the *type* of an expression is a reference type (as required for the `synchronized` statement), then the *value* of that expression is either `null` or an object. The two blocks in your posted code are not mutually exclusive unless the two `toString()` calls return the same object reference (`path1.toString() == path2.toString()`).

Comment: That is the opposite of what the cited reference tells us. It says, "Otherwise, let the non-null value of the Expression be V. The executing thread locks the monitor associated with V." It locks the monitor associated with the expression, not on the reference as this answer purports. Furthermore, as §17.1 states, the monitor is associated with the object, not the reference. "Each object in Java is associated with a monitor, which a thread can lock or unlock."

Comment: @LewBloch Again that's a distinction without a difference. It is a reference-valued expression.

Comment: Saying the opposite of the JLS rather does make a difference, particularly when it addresses the exact question the OP asked and gives the opposite answer. Not only that, but you only have to read fora like this one for a matter of minutes before you see how much damage the confusion between object and reference (pointer) causes. It matters in locks, GC, polymorphism, copying and cloning, immutability, argument passing (and whether it's by value) - really everything. So your claim that it's "a distinction without a difference" is as opposite to truth as the answer it tries to defend.

Comment: @LewBloch - Fair point. I've updated my wording slightly to clarify that Java locks on objects, not on references.